# What API does Qt use for interacting with the Windows clipboard?

Tags: qt, clipboard

I've been browsing the Qt source code trying to find the actual system calls but it seems Qt doesn't use the Windows API documented on MSDN. For example grepping the source for "GetClipboardData" returns results in two files:

qclipboard_win.cpp:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WINCE)
...
HANDLE clipData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
```

qaxserverbase.cpp:

```
STDMETHOD(GetClipboardData)(DWORD dwReserved, IDataObject** ppDataObject);
...
HRESULT WINAPI QAxServerBase::GetClipboardData(DWORD, IDataObject**)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

and "SetClipboardData":

qclipboard_win.cpp:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WINCE)
...
result = SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, wcsdup(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t *> (data->text().utf16()))) != NULL;
```

Neither of which seems useful, since they're being declared for Win CE/Mobile.

Answer (score 3):

My Qt (4.8.1) uses [OleSetClipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [OleGetClipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The lines you got to are never reached in regular windows, as only in case of `#if defined(Q_OS_WINCE)` Qt uses `#define OleSetClipboard QtCeSetClipboard` and `#define OleGetClipboard QtCeGetClipboard`, and otherwise uses system-provided versions of those functions.

It was a little dificult to see this `#if defined` though, so you are excused ;)

It is so at least on my Qt version. If you are talking about qt, and especially about it's internals, you should menstion the version, right?